# PHP Array Search - key => string

Tags: php, arrays

I got some trouble with `in_array()`

```
$list = array(
    "files/" => "/system/application/files/_index.php",
    "misc/chat/" => "/system/application/misc/chat/_index.php"
);
```

I have this `$_GET['f']` which holds the string `files/`.
How can I search through the array for possible matches?

If the string is found in the array, then the file should be included

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_key_exists` is a function that returns true of the supplied key is in the array.

```
if(array_key_exists( $_GET['f'], $list )) {
    echo $list[$_GET['f']];
}
```

Comment: +1 Eek, I never even knew of `array_key_exists()`.  Better than my solution.

Comment: Only by a single function call :) besides, I think ircmaxwell got us both.

Comment: I wouldn't call either of these two "complex".  In fact, there is a case where `array_key_exists` should be used over `isset`: when the array element value can be `null` and you want it to return true (isset would return false).  But that's not the case here.  My issue with AKE is that it's not trivial to realize which is the array unless you memorize parameter order or look it up.  The isset call just looks like a normal array access, so it's easy to tell if it's switched at a glance...

Answer (score 6):

It's really simple.  All you need to do is check if the array element is set.  The language construct that's usually used is [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) (yes, it's that obvious)...

```
if (isset($list[$_GET['f']])) {
}
```

There's no need to call a function for this, `isset` is cleaner and easier to read (IMHO)...

Note that `isset` is not actually a function.  It's a language construct.  That has a few implications:

1. You can't use `isset` on the return from a function (`isset(foo())` won't work).  It will only work on a variable (or a composition of variables such as array accessing or object accessing).
2. It doesn't have the overhead of a function call, so it's always fast.  The overall overhead of a function call is a micro-optimization to worry about, but it's worth mentioning if you're in a tight loop, it can add up.
3. You can't call isset as a variable function.  This won't work:

   ```
   $func = 'isset';
   $func($var);
   ```

Comment: Somewhat counterintuitively, this will result in an error (or a notice, depending on the error reporting level) if there is no GET parameter called `f`.

Comment: Also, with longer variable names `isset()` can mask typos in the variable name, so `array_key_exists()`˙results in safer code. That said, I tend to be lazy and use `isset()` myself...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `in_array()` in conjunction with [`array_keys()`](http://us.php.net/manual/function.array-keys.php):

```
if (in_array($_GET['f'], array_keys($list))) {
  // it's in the array
}
```

`array_keys()` returns an array of the keys from its input array.  Using `$list` as input, it would produce:

```
array("files/", "misc/chat/");
```

Then you use `in_array()` to search the output from `array_keys()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists).

```
if(array_key_exists($_GET['f'], $list)){
  // Do something with $list[$_GET['f']];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in_array() searches array for key using loose comparison unless strict is set. 
it's like below.

```
foreach ($array as $value){
    if ($key == $value){
        return true;
    }
}
```

My way.

```
function include_in_array($key, $array)
{
    foreach($array as $value){
        if ( strpos($value, $key) !== false ){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```